# Change account ownership and its affect on related records

Tags: apex

Does changing ownership of an account through apex automatically change ownership of related records like opportunity, contact etc?

While  making the change through UI, there is a text which says these related records would change and there are checkboxes to select the change of related records.

Would these related records change or do we need to change them from apex? Does the email for ownership also need to written in apex while changing through code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, we need to understand how Ownership works and how it effects [Sharing](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_bulk_sharing_understanding.htm)

> **Record Ownership**
>
> Each record is owned by a user or optionally a queue for custom
>   objects, cases and leads. The record owner is automatically granted
>   Full Access, allowing them to view, edit, transfer, share, and delete
>   the record.

When looking at the different types of relationships (lookup and master-detail) and [how they effect ownership](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/relationships_among_objects.htm), we know:

> **Master-Detail (1:n)** — A parent-child relationship in which the master object controls certain behaviors of the detail object:
>
> - *The Owner field on the detail object is not available and is automatically set to the owner of its associated master record. Custom
>     objects on the detail side of a master-detail relationship cannot have
>     sharing rules, manual sharing, or queues, as these require the Owner
>     field.*
> - *The detail record inherits the sharing and security settings of its master record.*
>
> **Lookup (1:n)** — *This type of relationship links two objects together, but has no effect on deletion or security.* Unlike
>   master-detail fields, lookup fields are not automatically required.
>   When you define a lookup relationship, data from one object can appear
>   as a custom related list on page layouts for the other object. See the
>   Salesforce online help for details.

Second, let's take a look at the Account documentation and the field that needs to changed to transfer ownership. From the [Account documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_account.htm):

> *OwnerId*
>
> **Type**   reference
>
> **Properties**   Create, Defaulted on create, Filter, Group, Sort, Update
>
> **Description** The ID of the user who currently owns this account. Default value is the user logged in to the API to perform the create.
>
> If you have set up account teams in your organization, updating this
>   field has different consequences depending on your version of the API:
>
> - For API version 12.0 and later, sharing records are kept, as they are for all objects.
> - For API version before 12.0, sharing records are deleted.
> - For API version 16.0 and later, users must have the “Transfer Record” permission in order to update (transfer) account ownership
>     using this field.

From the UI, we know we can [change owners](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/account_owner.htm) and [transfer associated records](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/account_owner_transfer.htm).

[image: Account Ownership]

However, from what we understand on how record ownership, we know that these ownership changes must have done outside of the normal OwnerId change (which is why they would even allow them to be optional). All the OwnerId truly controls is the Account owner and their subsequent child objects from a Master-Detail relationship. This means that to transfer opportunities, transfer cases, send a notification email, etc must all be handled manually in your Apex code.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If the realtionship is lookup then you will need trigger .Since changing through apex for Account wont change the owner Id of the related records.

If the relationship is master-detail then the child records derive ownerId from parent .Infact the child object dont have OwnerId field.