# Apex get list of related records from junction object

Tags: apex

I have two objects, Financial_Account and Client; they are connected with master-detail relationships to Client_Financial_Account_Relationship object. In a trigger on 'Financial_Account' I want to compare a field from Financial_Account and one on Client. My guess is to query for the junction object where Financial_Account_Id is equal to the one in my loop. Am I right there, is this the best way ? If so then how can do I get a list of all the associated records ?

I'm thinking something like this:

```
public static void checkOfferEnrollmentDateChange(List<Financial_Account__c> financialAccounts) {

        List<Client_Financial_Account_Relationship__c> relatedClients = 
 [Select ID,Customer__c,Financial_Account__c From Client_Financial_Account_Relationship__c Where IN :financialAccounts];

}
```

[Junction object in Salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/114617/junction-object-in-salesforce)

[Change account ownership and its affect on related records](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5274/change-account-ownership-and-its-affect-on-related-records)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, you just need to query the associated parent records on each side:

```
List<Client_Financial_Account_Relationship__c> relatedClients = 
 [Select ID,Customer__r.SomeField__c,Financial_Account__r.SomeField__c From Client_Financial_Account_Relationship__c Where Financial_Account__c IN :financialAccounts];
for(CLient_Financial_Account_Relationship__c rel: relatedClients) {
  if(rel.Customer__r.SomeField__c == rel.Financial_Account__r.SomeField__c) {
```

Of course, this is just hypothetical code, but it should get you started.

Comment: Thanks ! for posterity: it's 'Where Financial_Account__c IN :financialAccounts] '

Comment: @madmax I just copied that line direct from your question, but I'll toss that in, too.

Comment: Can you update object through the relationship__r field? As in: ' update rel.Customer__r; '

Comment: @madmax It's unusual to do that, but it should work. Ideally, you should put all records you intend to update in to a list.